# AngularJS property not bound on first call

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm brand new to AngularJS and i'm trying to implement a simple binding.

I have html like this (simplified):

```
<html ng-app>
  <div id="divController" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="button" ng-click="GetNumbers();" />
      <input type="text" value="{{numbers.Total}}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

and controller like this:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {

$scope.numbers = new Object();


$scope.GetNumbers = function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "page.aspx/GetCurrentNumbers",
        data: '{name: "test"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}

function OnSuccess(response) {

    var returnValue = JSON.parse(response.d);
    alert(returnValue.Total);
    $scope.numbers = returnValue;
}
}
```

First time i click the button nothing happens, however on the second click the input value gets updated. Both times alert outputs the same value.

Why does it not bind on the first click?

Comment: can you give a fiddle or plunker for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making an HTTP call outside the world of AngularJS by using directly a jQuery function. 
So angularJS can't refresh alone its template based on $scope vars updates done on the jquery ajax OnSuccess callback ...

it's only when doing the second ng-click that angular look at its $scope variables to see if something as changed (digest cycle)

So, to correct your problem: stop using jquery `$.ajax` and use angular internal mechanisms of [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) or [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) ($http + more features). That way angular will know it must update templates on http success/fail